# responsive web design video container whitespace

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to make a responsive web site and the problem I am facing currently is that when I minimize the browser size, my background video leaves a chunk of whitespace. It does not fill the size of the header and the following div after that is displayed after the whitespace.

As far as getting rid of video-container and using 100vw and 100vh on video-bg, I have tried and it does not work because my video is zoomed in at that point and does not display the entirety of the video.

https://www.videezy.com/urban/3951-top-to-bottom-panning-shot-of-downtown-los-angeles-4k

The above link is to download the video I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#block {
    background-color: black;
    height: 500px;
}
.embed-container { 
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
    height: 0; overflow: 
    hidden; 
    max-width: 100%; 
} 
.embed-container video, /*.embed-container object, .embed-container embed*/ { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
</style>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='embed-container'>
            <video autoplay muted allowfullscreen>
                <source src="downtownla.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="block">
            1
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

My expected goal is to be able to have a video that is responsive and allows for the following div to be displayed immediately after without any whitespace.

Comment: can you setup fiddle for your code.. whcih video are you using Youtube?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/48m5k2bt/2/ The video doesn't work here so I gave a link uptop instead if you could try it on Sublime

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for as you have not mentioned details about if you want to link YouTube or the one mentioned in the link.

Below website will help you setup responsive videos from different platforms

https://embedresponsively.com/

YouTube Embedded video example

```
<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/QILiHiTD3uc' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Also look at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Comment: Oh, I would like the video to serve as a background. When anyone enters the website, they will be greeted with the video that plays automatically. I do not want it to be where they have the option to click on the video, etc.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fullscreen_video      something like the video in this link, but where my video is not zoomed in and the div following is attached immediately without any whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be all right now.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid .header {
  position: relative;
}

.video-container {
  z-index: -100;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#video-bg {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#block1 {
  background: black;
}

#block2 {
  background: yellow;
}

#block3 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid header"> 
  <div class="header">

    <div class="video-container">
      <video autoplay muted id="video-bg">

        <source src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/003/951/original/downtownla.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>

      </video>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="block1" class="block">

</div>
<div id="block2" class="block">

</div>
<div id="block3" class="block">

</div>
```

Comment: This is a lot better than what I had before! Is it possible to get rid of the whitespace below? I have noticed that that the container is bigger than the video and am trying to resolve it myself as well.

Comment: I edited my answer. Write whether you wanted such an effect.

Comment: My desired effect would be for the video to be the width of the browser size and preferably only vh. The two most important things are width of browser and no whitespace from video to the next div. The first answer was more in line with what I desire, just no whitespace at the bottom.

Comment: Your first edit was the most similar to what I am looking for. If the whitespace on the bottom was able to be removed it would be perfect. I was using vh and 100% on height for the container and video respectively so that the video would be the size of the screen only as the final product i desire is for the video only to be the size of the individuals browser so that I can section each div as a 'page of its own'

Comment: Everything is ready, check now. Regarding the height of the video, it is not possible to do 100vh, because you will get white stripes at the bottom and top. You can change my code to find out why I did it.

Comment: First and foremost, I appreciate your help with this. If you are able to find a way so that the video width is able to take up 100% of the browser that would be amazing. Nonetheless, thank you and I will update you if I resolve the issue.

Comment: I have solved it! You need to add object-fit:cover to the #video-bg css and the video will fit the length of the screen!

Comment: Take a look now at the effect. I added `object-fit: fill;` and it fits your description but for me it has nothing to do with responsiveness, because on some screens it may look bad, and different videos have different screen ratio.